# Show custom SVG marker in highstock

Tags: svg, charts, highcharts, marker

I am trying to create chart as below [image]

But not sure how to create a marker as in image

Any pointer to add custom SVG image with a letter inside will help, Thanks

Comment: Through some read and pointers in stack over able to get  some chart as below in fiddle

     https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/87tbj5x2/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the shape of `series.flags` by using inbuilt shapes or add it as an image.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8cv1tL0g/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.flags.shape

You can also use Highcharts.SVGRenderer to draw any shape on the chart.

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer